# Сортировка по окончаниям

Tags: php, python

Как сделать сортировку слов по максимальной схожести окончаний слов (что бы более похожие слова шли первыми).
Есть примерно 1000 слов, которые нужно отсортировать по количеству похожих букв, на  которые слова заканчиваются. Например, сначала идут слова, у которых последние 5 букв одинаковые, потом у которых последние 4 буквы, потом у которых 3 буквы и так далее.

Пробовал в Excel, но получается только сортировка по алфавиту
на Python нужной функции не нашел.

Вот пример, какие слова должны идти в первую очередь(максимально схожие по окончанию)
nagging
bragging
dragging
begging
digging
jogging
bugging
hugging
mugging

Как это проще всего реализовать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно переставить все буквы в обратном порядке и отсортировать

Как сделать на [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php), [Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_reverse_string.asp), [Excel](https://spreadsheetplanet.com/reverse-text-string-excel/#:%7E:text=Reverse%20a%20Text%20String%20in%20Excel%20using%20TRANSPOSE%20Formula,-Although%20the%20above&text=In%20cell%20B1%2C%20type%20the%20formula%3A,reversed%20and%20separated%20by%20commas.), [MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_reverse.asp)

Я наверно бы в БД сделал - обрабатывать проще

```
SELECT words, words_rev, LEFT(words_rev, 6) AS rev FROM table ORDER BY rev;
```